# What is the difference between apparently identical vector output from for loop and logical subsetting function in r when calling them with sapply?

Tags: r, lapply

I am a beginner in the r language, and encountered something that has baffled me while trying to learn.  I have written a function that looks at a vector and returns all the negative values from it.  I've done this two ways, once using a for loop like so:

```
#doing it with a for loop
below_zero <- function(x) {
    build <- c()
    for(i in x) {
        if(i < 0) {
        build <- append(build, i)
        }
    }
    return(build)
}
```

...and alternatively, to attempt to achieve the same thing using logical subsetting:

```
 #doing it with logical subsetting
below_zero2 <- function(x) {
   negatives <- x[x < 0]
   return(negatives)
}
```

Running each of the above on a sample vector containing positive and negative numbers at first glance seems to give identical results e.g.

```
> first <- below_zero(c(1,2,3,-4,-5,-6))
> second <- below_zero2(c(1,2,3,-4,-5,-6))
> first
[1] -4 -5 -6
> second
[1] -4 -5 -6
> str(first)
 num [1:3] -4 -5 -6
> str(second)
 num [1:3] -4 -5 -6
```

So far everything as expected.  However, the problem comes when I try calling the two functions with sapply or lapply.  They now give slightly different feedback:

```
> lapply(c(1,2,3,-4,-5,-6), below_zero)
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
[1] -4

[[5]]
[1] -5

[[6]]
[1] -6

> lapply(c(1,2,3,-4,-5,-6), below_zero2)
[[1]]
numeric(0)

[[2]]
numeric(0)

[[3]]
numeric(0)

[[4]]
[1] -4

[[5]]
[1] -5

[[6]]
[1] -6
```

Could someone please explain to me where this difference comes from (NULLS when using the loop but 0's when using the subsetting)?  i'm not actually trying to achieve a particular result here just improve my understanding of how it works.

Thanks
Paul

Comment: You're not getting 0's but zero-length vectors in the second case. Why do you use `lapply`? In the `lapply` you are calling the function on each element of `c(1,2,3,-4,-5,-6)` and not on the whole vector. For the `NULL` vs `numeric(0)` part, see `c()` (used in the first function and returned if no negatives) vs `1[FALSE]` (used in second function when you subset with only `FALSE`s because of no negatives).

Comment: Thanks!  My mistake was in assuming c() would create a vector of length 0 then.